# How to create an algorithm to display remaining number value from an input?

Tags: python

I'm working on an ATM algorithm where the user inputs the amount of money they want to deposit. The code should then pop out the correct number bills required like hundreds, fifties, twenties, tens, and ones.

So, if I input 19 or 55 into this algorithm, it pops out at 1 ten or 1 fifty without the remaining 9 or 5.

```
money = int(input("Enter amount between 1 and 200: "))
hundreds = money // 100
fifties = money // 50
twenties = money // 20
tens = money // 10
fives = money // 5
ones = money // 1

if (money > 200 or money < 1):
  print("Invalid amount. Enter a number between 1 and 200.")
else:
  print("You have deposited", money, "dollar bill(s).")
  if (money >= 100):
    print("Hundreds:", hundreds)
  elif (money >= 50):
    print("Fifties:", fifties)
  elif (money >= 20):
    print("Twenties:", twenties)
  elif (money >= 10):
    print("Tens:", tens)
  elif (money >= 5):
    print("Fives:", fives)
  elif (money >= 1):
    print("Ones:", ones)
```

Output:

```
Enter amount between 1 and 200: 19
You have deposited 19 dollar bill(s).
Tens: 1

Enter amount between 1 and 200: 55
You have deposited 19 dollar bill(s).
Fifties: 1
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a single condition. You need a loop that goes through each denomination. Calculate the number of hundreds, display that, then get the remainder. Repeat with fifties, and so on.

Comment: Do you need to handle multiple different sets of bills? E.g. $20 can be one twenty, two tens, four fives, one ten and two fives, etc.

Comment: @Barmar For now I think its best for the user to just get 1 twenty bill if they input 20. Or 1 twenty and 1 five if they input 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
money = int(input("Enter amount between 1 and 200: "))
if money > 200 or money < 1:
    print("Invalid amount. Enter a number between 1 and 200.")
print("You have deposited", money, "dollar bill(s).")

hundreds = money // 100
money = money % 100
fifties = money // 50
money = money % 50
twenties = money // 20
money = money % 20
tens = money // 10
money = money % 10
fives = money // 5
money = money % 5
ones = money // 1


print("Hundreds:", hundreds)
print("Fifties:", fifties)
print("Twenties:", twenties)
print("Tens:", tens)
print("Fives:", fives)
print("Ones:", ones)
```

Look up the Modulo operator in Python (%). Hope I was helpful.

What this code does is divides the money sequentially, first by 100, then 50 etc as you were already doing. In between those steps, however, we can get the modulo of the money which is the remainder of the division by the note value (what's left over after we divide it). We can then divide the remainder of the division by each note value, and do this until there is no more remainder.

Comment: Don't just post code, explain how it fixes the problem.

Comment: I will edit my post and explain how I fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are a student, I suggest the following. Try yourself to find the answers of the questions given below my coding. This will make you understand the code well.

```
money = int(input("Enter amount between 1 and 200: \n"))
hundred, fifty,twenty,tens,five, ones = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
if money > 200:
    print('Enter the money below 200')
if money >= 100:
    hundred = str(money //100) +' hundreds'
    money = money % 100
if money in range(50, 100):
    fifty = str(money // 50) +' fifties'
    money = money % 50
if money in range(20, 50):
    twenty = str(money // 20) + ' twenties'
    money = money % 20
if money in range(10, 20):
    tens = str(money // 10) + ' tens'
    money = money % 10
if money in range(5, 10):
    five = str(money // 5) + ' fives'
    money = money % 5
if money in range(1, 5):
    ones = str(money) + ' ones'
else:
    print('Enter atleast one rupee')

s = ''
for x in [hundred, fifty, twenty, tens, five, ones]:
    if x != 0:
        s = s + x + ','
s= s[:-1] + '.'

print(s)

#input : 196
#output : 1 hundreds,1 fifties,2 twenties,1 fives,1 ones.
```

Now questions:

1. Why are values of hundred, fifty,twenty,tens,five and ones declared as 0 in the beginning?
2. Why is the same variable name 'money' given while calculating money % value ?
3. Why a conditional statement `if x != 0:` is given inside the `for` loop?
4. What is the purpose of the command `s= s[:-1] + '.'`?

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll play around with it